# Javascript won't display message

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I'm trying to create a simple program where a user needs to pick a maximum number, then try to guess a number between 1 and that maximum number. When they enter their guess, I need to validate the input, and offer a choice of feedback: different messages if it's (1) not a number, (2) a number not within the range, (3) the correct guess, (4) too high, but within range, and (5) too low, but within range.

```js
function do_guess(prompt) {
  let valid_input = false;
  let guess = Number(document.getElementById("guess").value);

  let message = document.getElementById("message");

  while (!valid_input) {
    input = window.prompt(prompt);

    guess = Number(input);

    if (isNaN(guess)) {
      message.innerHTML = "That is not a number!";
    } else if (guess < 1 || guess > val) {
      // val = max_num - "I wasn't sure how to code this."
      message.innerHTML = "That number is not in the range, try again.";
    } else if (guess == num) {
      valid_input = true;
      message.innerHTML = "You got it!";
    } else if (guess > num) {
      message.innerHTML = "No, try a lower number.";
    } else {
      message.innerHTML = "No, try a higher number.";
    }
  }
}
do_guess("Number from 1 to 10")
```

```html
Guess <input id="guess" value="" />
<div id="message"></div>
```

Comment: Please format your code properly and NOTE `NaN == NaN`  gives `false`. Use `isNaN()` instead.

Comment: You are using val before it exists

Comment: It looks like your "guess" input box is redundant as you're using a window.prompt instead.

Comment: `"message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: val is not defined",`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements, I'm loading the max_val from the input box and calling the do_guess function with a new button.

```
function do_guess(prompt) {
  let valid_input = false;
  let max_val = Number(document.getElementById("guess").value);
  let message = document.getElementById("message");
  let output = '';
  let num = Math.floor((Math.random() * max_val) + 1);
  prompt = prompt + max_val;
  
  while (!valid_input) {
    input = window.prompt(prompt + output);

    let guess = Number(input);

    if (isNaN(guess)) {
      output = " That is not a number!";
    } else if (guess < 1|| guess > max_val) {
      output = " That number is not in the range, try again.";
    } else if (guess == num) {
      valid_input = true;
      message.innerHTML = "You got it!";
    } else if (guess > num) {
      output = " No, try a lower number.";
    } else {
      output = " No, try a higher number.";
    }
  }
}
```

```
Max Guess <input id="guess" value="" />
<div id="message"></div>
<button onClick="javascript:do_guess('Number from 1 to ')">
 Guess
</button>
```

Comment: do you mean having the max value be an input part of the guess? because they are two different inputs by the user: first they tell me what the max value they want their guessing game to be for, then they guess a number.

Comment: Sorry, I updated my code after writing that sentence. In my example, clicking the guess button will pull the max_val from the input box, call random to generate a random number between 1 and the inputted max_val. Then it uses the window.prompt function, that you were using in your example, to ask the user their input.

Comment: I've created a JSFiddle for this here: https://jsfiddle.net/mo4phrqs/

Comment: @Maggie, if that answers your question, please mark as an answer.